# How to change a document in mongodb with findOneAndUpdate depending if it's an insert or an update

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have this function that upserts in database.

```
upsert = (req, res) => {
  return Promise.all(req.body.map(resource => {
    return Resource.findOneAndUpdate({
      resource_id: resource.id
    }, 
    {
      $set: {
        title: resource.title,
        seller_id: resource.seller_id,
        initial_quantity: resource.quantity,
        quantity: 0
      }
    },
    {
      upsert: true,
      new: true
    });
  }))
  .then(
    res.status(200).json({ message: "OK" })
  )
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Error" });
  });
}
```

It is working as expected. Now I want to be able to:

- Save 0 in quantity, if its a new document
- Save quantity(db) + resource.quantity (request), if it is an update

How could I do this?

Comment: So if the document doesn't already exist, you to completely ignore the `resource.quantity`?

Comment: I have set up a default in the model

Answer (score 0):

Use the pipeline form of update to use aggregation operators in the update:

```
Resource.findOneAndUpdate(
  {"resource_id": resource.id},
  [{$set: {
      quantity: {$cond: {
          if: {$eq: [{$ifNull: ["$quantity","null"]}, "null"]},
          then: 0,
          else: {$sum: ["$quantity", resource.quantity]}
      }},
      title: resource.title,
      seller_id: resource.seller_id,
      initial_quantity: resource.quantity
  }}],
  {
   upsert: true,
   new: true
  }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XG6ixJsEKSu)